# Aus der Fähre fahren?

Tags: preposition

I always have trouble to decide what preposition I should use. Is "aus" here the proper word or do I have to use another preposition?

Comment: The two near simultaneous answers show, that your question isn't clear. What is it, that you want to express?

Comment: You can use the following prepositions with "driving" + "ferry": aus, auf, um, gegen, hinter, vor, in, neben, nahe, entlang, über, unter, zu, bei, an, seitlich... and I am sure there are more. Which preposition to use depends on what you want to say.

Comment: As @Toscho already mentioned you should add more context to your question, as (especially with prepositions) context is the strongest influence on what a certain word means.

Answer (score 5):

Saying "Aus der Fähre fahren" isn't quite common in german (but still valid). You would normally say "Von der Fähre fahren".

The difference is

> "Aus der Fähre fahren" means "Driving out of the ferry"

while

> "Von der Fähre fahren" says "Driving off the ferry"

which is quite more common.

Answer (score 4):

> Aus der Fähre fahren

**implies a closed structure.** If it's a rather big ferry you're leaving - like the one below - your fine with it.

[image]

More general in use is

> Von der Fähre fahren

Can be used even for the big one above. But you would not use `aus` when leaving this ferry:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apart from generic prepositions, there are three special ones here:

> *mit* der Fähre fahren → Ich fahre mit der Fähre *nach Schweden*. (Zielangabe)
>
> *auf* der Fähre fahren → Ich fahre *gerade* auf der Fähre über die Ostsee. (Zustandsangabe)
>
> Fähre fahren → *Wie* fahrt ihr nach Schweden? Wir fahren Fähre. (Methodenangabe)

The case without preposition might sound odd due to the similarity of `fahren` and `Fähre`.